# React - Selenium - Testing project - How to get nth element

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Using C# I am writing unit tests using Selenium (testing my react front end)...My html is:

```
   <article class="company-details-container">
       <div class="details-header">...</div>           
       <div class="details-header">...</div>
           <section class="details-new-section>...</section>
       <div class="details-header">...</div>
       <div class="details-header">...</div>
       <div class="details-header">...</div>
    </article>
```

Section tag is the contents of each div, when you click on a div a new section appears with the divs contents... when the page loads the second div is already open, which is why the section tag is shown

I would like to click the first element inside the last div...
I am able to click the first element inside the first div by...

```
IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".details-header"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", elementa);
```

I have tried `IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".details-header[0]"));` but this is not working.

ANy help please?

Comment: How this works? once you click on the last div it expand and then you need to click on the first div or you can directly clicks on last div and then first div of the last div element?

Comment: yes we can click on last div by saying IWebElement elementa2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='details-header'])[last()]"));  then this will expand and we can say   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".button.is-primary")).Click();  but how do I select the nth item of div, if I want to select the 2nd div for exmaple? (instead of the last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following `xpath` to click on last div, then first div of last div.

```
IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//div[@class='details-header'])[last()]/div[1]"));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply this has helped me... What about if I wanted to select the second div inside 'details-header'? I have tried IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//div[@class='details-header'])[second()]")) but this did not work

Comment: This would be like this. `IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("(//div[@class='details-header'])[2]"))`

Answer (score 0):

// Find the last div with class 'details-header'
IWebElement lastDiv = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.details-header:last-of-type"));

// Find the first child element inside the last div
IWebElement firstElementInLastDiv = lastDiv.FindElement(By.CssSelector(":first-child"));

// Click on the first child element inside the last div
firstElementInLastDiv.Click();

Comment: thanks for reply, this did not work, please see orignal Q, i forgot to add bit about section if that changes anything thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

CssSelector: article[class='company-details-container'] > div:last-of-type > yourelementinsidediv:nth-child(1)